# When I assign an object to a property of an object, does the property become an object? If so, how do I access the first object via the second one?

Tags: javascript

I have divided this question into several sub-questions, because they are all related, and make up the pieces to what I do not understand.

First and foremost, when I assign an object to a property, does that property become an object too?

Example:

```js
var object1 = new Object();
object1.color = "red";


var newobject = { 
  "obname": object1
}
```

Here, I instantiate an object `object1`, and then I instantiate another object, `newobject`, and assign the first object, `object1` as a value to the property `obname` of the `newobject` object.

Now, is `obname` now an object? How should I view `obname` right now?

This leads me to the sub-second question.

How do I now access the properties of `object1` via `newobject`?

```js
    var object1 = new Object();
    object1.color = "red";


    var newobject = { 
      "obname": object1
    }
    
    alert(newobject.obname);
```

- Targeting the `obname` returns `[object object]`. **Why?**
- Targeting `obname.object1` returns `undefined`. **Why?**
- Targeting `obname.object1.color` returns error. **Why?**

I can only access the properties of `object1` this way:

```js
var object1 = new Object();
object1.color = "red";


var newobject = { 
  "obname": object1
}

alert(newobject.obname.color);
```

..by only targeting `obname`, and then the property of the `object1`.

The last important sub-question: **Why does this work?**

`color` is not a property of `obname`, so why am I able to access it this way?

Comment: "color is not a property of obname" - why not?

Comment: `obname` is not an object. It's a property name that points to whatever value is assigned to it. In this case, an object with a property named `color`. It's not a free-floating property, it only exists within `newobject`. That's why you have to access color as `newobject.obname.color`

Comment: Consider `const object2 = newobject.obname; console.log(object2.color)`. Hint` object2 === object1`.

Comment: Do you understand what an *object* is (in general, in OOP, and in JS specifically)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `color` is assigned to the first object, `object1`. If `obname` is not an object, how am I able to access the property of the other object, `object1` via `obname`? I am assigning the object `object1` to the property `obname`. So, does that mean, all the properties of `object1` are not also properties of the property `obname`? How come?

Comment: @Bergi Your example is not an analogy for my examples. You are creating a new object, `object2, and assigning a property of another object to it. In your example, is `obname` an object, or a property? Your example is not clear. If `color` is a property of `obname`, how can you access it via `object2`?

Comment: In general, I think `object` is just a value, a node or a variable in the DOM. In OOP, I thought it's a variable that contains properties and methods.

Comment: "In OOP, I thought it's a variable that contains properties and methods." - no, variable contains nothing. It's just a name. Objects contains properties and method, and the same object can have different names. In Bergi's example, `object2` and `object1` point to the same object.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Can you be more specific? What do you mean by variables contain nothing. They're just a name? Then what is the purpose of a variable? Also, in Bergi's example, `object2` is a variable, is it not? And then you assign the property of `newobject` to that variable. Is that incorrect? It's like saying var test = object.color, now the variable `test` contains the value of the `color` property. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @TaishoMori No, the example did not create a new object, it did create a new variable `object2`. An object is not a variable that contains properties, it is independent from the concept of variables. An object is the bag of properties itself (or rather, it is a *reference value* pointing to such a bag). A variable can *hold* such a value, just like it can hold a simple number. The same for properties - it can hold any value, object reference or primitive value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked several questions here, so I'll try to hit them all....

```js
var object1 = new Object();
object1.color = "red";

var newobject = { 
  "obname": object1
}
```

> Now, is `obname` now an object? How should I view `obname` right now?

Technically, `obname` is a "property" or "key" name of the `newObject` object and it stores a reference to the `object1` object.

Next:

```js
var object1 = new Object();
object1.color = "red";


var newobject = { 
  "obname": object1
}

alert(newobject.obname.color);
```

> How do I now access the properties of object1 via newobject?

The same way to do of any other object, but you will have to access the property of the first object that stores a reference to the second one, so you'll use two levels of "dot notation"

```js
var object1 = new Object();
object1.color = "red";

var newobject = { 
  "obname": object1
}

alert(newobject.obname.color);
```

> Targeting the `obname` returns `[object object]`. Why?

Because you've attempted to "print" (via an `alert`) an entire object and that's what you get when you try to treat an entire object as a string.

> Targeting obname.object1 returns undefined. Why?

Because `object1` is not declared within `obname`, it's "referenced" via the `obname` property. Think of this as a pointer... `obname` points to where `object1` can be found.

> Targeting obname.object1.color returns error. Why?

Because `obname` is a pointer to `object1` and `object1` doesn't have a property called `object1`.

Comment: But I am targeting the property `color` of `object1`, not a property called `object1`? Also, what about the last question? Why does `obname.color` returns the value of that property, since `color` is not assigned as a property to `obname`? I thought `obname` just references the object `object1`, so why am I able to access the property of `object1` via `obname`?

Comment: It feels very illogical to not be able to access the property `color` by saying `obname.object1.color`, but to be able to access it by omitting the `object1`, and just saying `obname.color` despite `color` being a property of `object1` not a property of `obname`.

Comment: @TaishoMori `obname` points to the `object1` object, so when you say `obname` you gain access to everything that `object` has, such as its `color` property. But `obname` does not have a property ***called*** `object1`, so you can't type `obname.object1` because `object1` is not a property ***name*** within `obname`.

Comment: @TaishoMori This may be new to you and I understand that, at first, this can be a little confusing, but this is not unique to JavaScript. All object-oriented languages work in roughly this way. It's very common. You need to be able to separate a property that ***references*** an object from the object itself.

Comment: @TaishoMori Here's a rough analogy. If you wanted to find out something from my sister, Lori, you could go to her directly and say "Lori, what's your favorite color?" (i.e. `lori.color`). But, if you wanted to go through me to get that info, I would reference my sister differently. That might be `Scott.sister.color`, where `sister` is just a reference to `Lori`. But to say `Scott.Lori.color` would be wrong because my sister isn't part of me directly.

Comment: @TaishoMori ... `Scott.Lori` would mean that `Scott` has a property named `Lori`, which doesn't make much sense. `Lori` is my `sister` and I have a ***relationship*** with her, which is what a property establishes here, a relationship or a pointer to some other completely separate thing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: oh, it's a good analogy, I like it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I get what you're saying. Ironically, your analogy confused me more than your actual technical explanation, so please stop using analogies with me :) Okay, so, when I type `obname.object3` it returns `undefined` because there is no such property assigned to `obname`, however, since `obname` is a reference to the object, so `obname` has access to the object, `object1`, well then, why is saying `obname` returns `[object object]` instead of the property and value assigned to that object `object1` directly?

Comment: @TaishoMori As I stated in my original answer, when you ask for an entire object to be treated as a string, you get it represented as `[Object object]` because you haven't asked for any particular characteristic of the object. Also, that wasn't SergioT that posted the analogy. That was me. Again, I understand that this can be tough when you are new to it, but most people do like analogies.

Comment: @TaishoMori You should back up and start at the beginning. [Here's a great tutorial to start with.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)_

Comment: Oops, I meant to @ you. Sorry. I understand now. Can I ask you one more thing? If we take the same situation, but instead of `object1`, I assign an array to the property `obname`, now If I target `obname`, it will again return `[object object]`. So why is that? Since Array is not an object the same way `object1` was, right? Although Arrays do contain properties and values like objects. So in that sense they are similar. By the way, I am studying from a book, but a lot of details are omitted, so I end up asking a lot of questions here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have to be going to bed now. I will reexamine all the answers again tomorrow, and If there's nothing else that I need to ask, I'll just give you the best answer. :)

Comment: @TaishoMori You're right that an `Array` is not exactly the same thing as an `Object`, but Arrays actually are a kind of Object, so you get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply think of obname is equivalent to object1 (It is an Object).

As you do access object1 properties (In this case property is color) You should be getting the value of the property as following:

object1.color which returns the value **"red"**

- Targeting the obname returns [object object]. Why?
  Because obname is an Object.

Think of it as:

```
var newobject = { 
  "obname": { "color" : "red"}
}
```

- Targeting obname.object1 returns undefined. Why?
- Targeting obname.object1.color returns error. Why?

Because obname does not have any property called object1. Instead obname and object1 are equivalent Objects (they have one property color as defined by yourself).

```
alert(newobject.obname.color);
```

This works because you are accessing obname property correctly.

To answer the question why is color a property of obname; That is because you have assign obname to object1 so they are the same

Comment: *You can simply think of obname is equivalent to object1 (It is an Object).* <-- No, you really shouldn't. `obname` is an object property that holds a reference to an object - - it, itself is not an object.

Comment: But I don't understand how are they equivalent objects? Am I not assigning the `object1` to `obname`? When I assign the `object1` to `obname`, am I assigning the properties and values, and presumably methods of `object1` to `obname`? I didn't thought that's how it works.

Comment: @ScottMarcus If it holds a reference to an object, why am I able to access directly the properties of that object without even referencing the `object1` itself?

Comment: @TaishoMori See my recent comment in reply to your other comment above.